# creating a process and killing it

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, clang

I'm working on an assignment that requires me to create a child process then wait for 300 seconds and kill that process, while the parent process should be killed 200 seconds after creating the child process.  I'm doing this in C++ in Ubuntu using the Clang++ compiler.  I'm very new to C++ and have been using Java for a while.  What I have now is probably more like psuedocode than anything else, I really doubt it works. When I compile it gives me errors regarding my kill() calls, I've tried things like *this.kill() or this.kill() and neither have worked. How do use the kill command?  Also, does this code look like it will do what I want?  I'm afraid it is not even close.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

class process{

public:
    process(){
        main();
    }


    void main(){
        process *parent = new process();
        int pid;
        pid=fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {   
            sleep(200);
            kill();
        }
        else
        {
            sleep(100);
            kill();
        }
    }   
};
```

Comment: Please don't use the deprecated homework tag.

Comment: Start with [the documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/kill.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `kill` system call requires a couple of arguments: a *process id* for the process to kill, and a specific signal. There is no version of the call with no arguments, to e.g. just kill the current process.

See the man page for kill, [here's](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) a linux version of the man page.

Note that frim *unistd.h* you also have access to the `getpid`  call that you can use to get the process id for the calling process, see [man getpid](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpid).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is structured like a Java command-line program where the main entry point is a function named `main()` inside some (unspecific) class. A C++ program uses main() as an entry point also however it must be a function at the top level, not a class method.

Typically you would have as a minimal C++ program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

In your program it would be best to avoid making a class completely; it's not necessary considering you're only running some simple procedural code.

Answer (score 0):

`kill` is a syscall for sending signals to processes, you must specify the proper signal as its second parameter(the first is the process id of the receiving process), like so:

```
kill(pid,SIGKILL);
```